# indexPathForRowAtPoint Error in a TableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Inside a button of a UITableViewCell, I have this function, that creates an automatic scroll to the next cell.

```
var tableView = self.superview?.superview

    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView : tableView)
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!

    if indexPath.row < tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) {
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:indexPath.row + 1, inSection:indexPath.section)
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(
            newIndexPath, atScrollPosition:.Top, animated: true)
    }
```

I have an error on the line: "let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!" saying: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Do you have any idea how to fix it? I would like to keep that code inside my UITableViewCell.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the value returned by superview

```
var tableView = self.superview?.superview as! UITableView
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However even if I cast the expression to NSIndexPath

     let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)! as? NSIndexPath

It still has the error:  "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: [Updated] Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @skifen128 What about 'let indexPath: NSIndexPath? = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!'

Comment: Try this 'var tableView = self.superview?.superview as! UITableView' and remove those stuff that I told you. It should work now.

Comment: Awsome! Thank you vm !!